# Is there an object which has a purpose of indefinite place holding in forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

I got a form. In this form there is a tab control and there is a menu strip. I would like the tab control to take up the space of the entire form; however, I do not want the menu strip to cover the top of it.

In order to combat this problem. I made a control and I made the panel the same size as the menu strip. I put added the panel control to the menu strip first and then I added the tab control; however, I did not get the desired result. Can someone show me how to get the result I desire?

This is what it looks like without the additional panel.

[image]

Here us the code :

```
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Panel placeholder = new Panel()
        //{
        //    MaximumSize = menuStrip1.MaximumSize,
        //    MinimumSize = menuStrip1.MaximumSize,
        //    Size = menuStrip1.Size,
        //    Padding = menuStrip1.Padding,
        //    Visible = true,
        //};
        //placeholder.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        //Controls.Add(placeholder);
        Controls.Add(InitNavigation());
    }

    TabControl InitNavigation()
    {
        //Declare All Variables
        TabControl control = new TabControl();
        TabPage queryPage = new TabPage();
        TabPage tablePage = new TabPage();
        control.TabPages.Add(queryPage);
        control.TabPages.Add(tablePage);

        //Customize Table Control 
        control.Top = menuStrip1.Size.Height;
        control.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        Padding Margin = control.Margin;
        MessageBox.Show("" + menuStrip1.Size.Height);
        //control.Margin = new Padding(Margin.Left,, Margin.Right, Margin.Bottom);

        //Customize Query Tab 
        queryPage.Text = "Queries";

        //Customize Table Page
        tablePage.Text = "Tables";
        control.Visible = true;
        return control;
    }
```

This is what it looks like with the panel
[image]
Here is the code:

```
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Panel placeholder = new Panel()
        {
            MaximumSize = menuStrip1.MaximumSize,
            MinimumSize = menuStrip1.MaximumSize,
            Size = menuStrip1.Size,
            Padding = menuStrip1.Padding,
            Visible = true,
        };
        placeholder.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        Controls.Add(placeholder);
        Controls.Add(InitNavigation());
    }

    TabControl InitNavigation()
    {
        //Declare All Variables
        TabControl control = new TabControl();
        TabPage queryPage = new TabPage();
        TabPage tablePage = new TabPage();
        control.TabPages.Add(queryPage);
        control.TabPages.Add(tablePage);

        //Customize Table Control 
        control.Top = menuStrip1.Size.Height;
        control.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        Padding Margin = control.Margin;
        MessageBox.Show("" + menuStrip1.Size.Height);
        //control.Margin = new Padding(Margin.Left,, Margin.Right, Margin.Bottom);

        //Customize Query Tab 
        queryPage.Text = "Queries";

        //Customize Table Page
        tablePage.Text = "Tables";
        control.Visible = true;
        return control;
    }
```

finally. This last picture just shows that the tabs are in fact there (its the same code as the first code posted except the menu strip visibility is set to false).
[image]

Any insight on how to fix this problem would be appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm missing here. If I create a new WinForm project, put a menu strip on it, and then add a tab control, all I have to do is set the tab control to Dock = Fill and it's perfect.

Comment: @JonB beat me to it... I tried the same thing he did with the same result... the tab control doesn't cover the menu strip.

Comment: Is it possible its because I didn't use the GUI that its missing some setting? I'm trying it out now.

Comment: @JonB I think its because System.Drawing.Point is not set for the navigation.Location. When I used the GUI it worked fine and I think thats the only difference that is visible to me. I guess there is probably no way to do it completely dynamically .

Comment: The GUI is just generating code for you. Draw it with the GUI and look at the .designer.cs file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fully docked control is underneath a top docked control, try bringing the fully docked control to the front (right click on it in the designer and select bring to front) this should fix it.

Comment: ironically enough. I later learned that this is actually the correct answer and I stumbled on this question again. Anyway, at least now we know the answer for future reference.